# Re-print an array in a certain format?

Tags: shell-script, sed, array

I wish to take 10 random lines of file, which is 100 lines long. First, I randomly generate 10 integers between 1 and 100 (inclusive) with

```
ind=$(shuf -i 1-100 -n 10 | sort -n)
```

Then, I wish to use `sed` to extract out those lines (indicated by `ind`). So I need to re-print the array `ind` to generate

```
<ind(1)>p;<ind(2)>p;...;<ind(10)>p
```

as in

```
sed -n '<ind(1)>p;<ind(2)>p;...;<ind(10)>p' ~/orig.txt > ~/short.txt
```

How may I do this?

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `ind` is a string, not an array. You must use:

```
ind=($(shuf -i 1-100 -n 10 | sort -n))
```

to make `ind` to be array (in shell support array like `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`).

Simply, you can try:

```
$ printf '%sp\n' $(shuf -i 1-100 -n 10 | sort -n) > /tmp/short.sed
$ sed -n -f /tmp/short.sed < orig.txt > short.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` based solution (without need of sorting):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} NR in a' <(shuf -i 1-100 -n 10) ~/orig.txt > ~/short.txt
```

And a pure GNU `awk` variant (without need of other external processes):

```
awk '
  BEGIN { srand(); do a[int(100*rand()+1)]; while (length(a)<10) }
  NR in a
' ~/orig.txt > ~/short.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to go the long way, creating a `sed` script to extract the lines from your file, just use `shuf` directly on the file:

```
shuf -n 10 ~/short.txt
```

If you want the lines in the order that they are found in the original file:

```
cat -n ~/short.txt | shuf -n 10 | sort -n | cut -f 2-
```

This enumerates the lines in the file, extracts 10 lines from it (in random order), sorts the extracted lines, and removes the numbering.

Answer (score 0):

## U could...

```
shuf -i 1-100 -n 10 | sort -n | sed 's/$/p;/' | sed -nf - orig.txt >short.txt
```

### or, under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
sed -nf <(sed 's/$/p;/' <(sort -n < <(shuf -i 1-100 -n 10))) <orig.txt >short.txt
```