# Find the complement set of an array?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, array

Following from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205919/re-print-an-array-in-a-certain-format), where I wish to extract 10 random lines from a file, I now wish to also have the remaining 90 lines as a separate file.

Since the document has 100 lines, indexing from 1 to 100, the problem boils down to
finding the complement set of `ind` within `1, 2, ..., 100`, where

```
ind=$(shuf -i 1-100 -n 10 | sort -n)
```

So my questions are

1. How can I generate the array `1, 2, ..., 100` efficiently? and
2. It seems that this can be done with `comm`. If so, how should I do `comm` on arrays (not files)?

Comment: Why not use the same `sed` command with `d` instead of `p`?

Comment: @muru Could you please elaborate why? I tried, using `d` gives me an empty file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my proposal from the other thread:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { srand(); do a[int(100*rand()+1)]; while (length(a)<10) }
  NR in a
' ~/orig.txt > ~/short.txt
```

this could be changed to create both files:

```
awk -v range=100 -v offset=1 -v amount=10 '
  BEGIN { srand(); do a[int(range*rand()+offset)]; while (length(a)<amount) }
  NR in a    { print > "short.txt" }
  !(NR in a) { print > "rest.txt" }
' ~/orig.txt
```

(Note that inside `awk` you cannot use `~`. It's possible, though, to use `HOME` through `ENVIRON[]`, as in: `print > ENVIRON["HOME"] "/short.txt"`, or resp., `print > ENVIRON["HOME"] "/rest.txt"`.)

Comment: This is elegant, but I am wondering why I get `awk: syntax error at source line 2
 context is
   BEGIN { srand(); do >>>  a[int(${ <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 2
awk: illegal statement at source line 2`.

Comment: @Sibbs Gambling; Where does that `$` and `{` come from that I see in your error message? (Are you using a modified version?) - In case you were trying to use **shell variables** in `awk` code (which doesn't work) I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, I changed `100` and `1` into two variables `${a}` and `${b}`.

Comment: @Sibbs Gambling; I added the parameter passing mechanism. Now you can replace the numbers in the call by your shell variables.

Comment: Great, it works now! One very quick follow-up: what if I also need to use variable in `{ print > "short.txt" }`? I tried `-v dir=$runDir` and then `{ print > "${dir}/short.txt" }`, but it is not working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sibbs Gambling; `awk` variables are just names. The `-v` definition is okay (though better quote the shell variable: `-v dir="$runDir"`), but not the part inside the program. In your case you'd use the variable just as `dir` and the string literal as `"/short.txt"`. All together that would be: `{ print > dir "/short.txt" }`.

Comment: Weird. I tried `{ print > dir "/short.txt" }`, which gives me `awk: syntax error at source line 3
 context is
    NR in a    { print > dir >>>  "/train.dat" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 3
awk: syntax error at source line 4`

Comment: @Sibbs Gambling; Are you maybe working on Solaris? - Solaris has a very old and broken `awk` as default; instead use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` (or `nawk`). - Otherwise try enclosing the concatenated objects in parenthesis: `{ print > (dir "/short.txt") }`

Comment: Great! Enclosing solves the problem. A BIG thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, on second thought - I worked *way* too hard on that. You just need this:

```
shuf -i 1-100 -n10 |
sed 's/$/{p;b\n}/' |
sed -nf - -e 'w separate_file' infile >outfile
```

Though you might need a literal newline in-place of the `n` in the `sed` substitution. Anyway that does the same as below - it just doesn't bother doing all of the other 90 lines - they just fall into place because they're in the file - so they don't need any special consideration.

Here's the whole deal:

```
set  " $(shuf -i 1-100 -n 10) "
while [ "$((i+=1))" -le 100 ]
do    [ -z "${1##*[!0-9]$i[!0-9]*}" ]
      printf "$i%.$((!$?))s%.$?s\n" p H 
done| sed -nf - -e '$!d;x;s/.//p' <infile >outfile
```

There - we just basically write a `sed` script that looks like:

```
1H
2H
3H
4p
5H
...
90p
91H
...
```

And so on through to 100. On the last line - after all of the randomly selected lines have already been `p`rinted, we e`x`change into `H`old space, `s///`ubstitute away the first inserted `\n`ewline character, and `p`rint the lot of the rest.

To do this without the shell loop you could do:

```
set  "$(shuf -i 1-100 -n 10)"
{ seq 100 | grep -Fxv "$1"; echo "$1"; } |
sed '1,90s/$/H/;91,$s/$/p/' |
sed -nf - -e '$!d;x;s/.//p' <infile >outfile
```

But I'm not sure whether on this scale that would be beneficial at all.

Anyway, I used a `seq 100` output file as a test, and after running it through it printed...

```
3
4
5
19
57
63
64
73
80
88
1
2
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
...
```

...and on through to 100 for all of the lines not included in the initial random 100.

Comment: @don_crissti: yeah - I probably would have as well - and definitely considered it - but I've already taken a [stern scolding](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205903/can-bash-brace-expansion-be-performed-within-quotes/205923?noredirect=1#comment347416_205923) about `$IFS` today and didn't want to hear it again. Anyway, it was also to demonstrate how to find the *complement* - that's why I used `grep -Fxv` on a full set and the `[ -z ... ]` test.

Comment: @don_crissti - Oh, and I guess I didn't realize at first that two outbuffers were wanted - so the bottom stuff all writes to the same stream, with the random selection output first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution with bash.
First, you might want to create an array from your ind variable:

```
ind=($(shuf -i 1-100 -n 10 | sort -n))
```

To create an array with numbers from 1..100, an easy way is this:

```
numbers=({1..100})
```

In order to get to the complement, I would utilize uniq -u. This command can sort out all duplicates from a already sorted list. The final paste command just puts all values into a single line again.

```
complement=($(echo ${ind[*]} ${numbers[*]} | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort -n | uniq -u | paste -sd " " - ))
echo ${complement[*]}
```

Just rethinking the question, all of this can also be done without bash arrays:

```
ind=$(shuf -i 1-100 -n 10 | sort -n)
echo $ind {1..100} | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort -n | uniq -u | paste -sd " " -
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do everything on the command line, but some problems are better solved with an actual programming language. As an example, a python based solution to your problem would be:

```py
import random
import pprint

with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
  # create a file filled with numbers from 00 to 99
  f.writelines(map(lambda x: "%02d\n" % x, range(100)))

with open("file.txt") as f:
  # read it and assign each line to array, strip newlines 
  ar = set(map(lambda x: x.strip(), f.readlines()))

selection = set(random.sample(ar, 10))
rest = ar - selection

pprint.pprint(selection)
pprint.pprint(rest)
```